# Polyfill object at angular.run()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, metaprogramming

I have need of an object fold like function so i am adding

```
if (!Object.prototype.reduce){
  Object.prototype.reduce = function(f,zero){
    var me = this;return Object.keys(this).reduce(function(accum, current){ return f(accum, current, me[current]) }, zero)
  }
}
```

to my angular run module, where i usally add Array definitions functions such as last , contains, etc...

But apparently this breaks angular. I cant explain why/how but i get different errors depending on which `page` im in.

I even may get a `f is not a function` referring to that argument f used as the callback function.

i added a

```
console.log('log: ','im beign called', this);
```

inside the definition of this new reduce and i discovered

```
log: im beign called Window {external: Object, chrome: Object, document: document, returnExports: undefined, angular: Object…}
```

So somethings is actually calling reduce. Or whatever i name it (changed to  Object.prototype.fold and got the same problems).

The question are why this happen and / or is there another way to achieve this?

Full error stack

> ! 
>   angular.js:12783TypeError: (tweeners[prop] || []).concat is not a function
>       at createTween (http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js:7921:43)
>       at Object.defaultPrefilter (http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js:8214:12)
>       at Animation (http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js:8010:41)
>       at HTMLHtmlElement.doAnimation (http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js:8344:16)
>       at Function.jQuery.extend.dequeue (http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js:3700:7)
>       at HTMLHtmlElement. (http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js:3742:13)
>       at Function.jQuery.extend.each (http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js:590:23)
>       at jQuery.fn.jQuery.each (http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js:237:17)
>       at jQuery.fn.extend.queue (http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js:3735:9)
>       at jQuery.fn.extend.animate (http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js:8355:9) undefined(anonymous function) @ angular.js:12783(anonymous function) @ angular.js:9535(anonymous function) @ angular-block-ui.js:22Scope.$broadcast @ angular.js:16684transitionTo @ angular-ui-router.js:3272(anonymous function) @ angular-ui-router.js:2383invoke @ angular.js:4560handleIfMatch @ angular-ui-router.js:1868(anonymous function) @ angular-ui-router.js:1925check @ angular-ui-router.js:2041update @ angular-ui-router.js:2050Scope.$broadcast @ angular.js:16682afterLocationChange @ angular.js:12627(anonymous function) @ angular.js:12613Scope.$eval @ angular.js:16359Scope.$digest @ angular.js:16175Scope.$apply @ angular.js:16467bootstrapApply @ angular.js:1686invoke @ angular.js:4560doBootstrap @ angular.js:1684bootstrap @ angular.js:1704(anonymous function) @ app.js:57fire @ jquery.js:2913self.add @ jquery.js:2959jQuery.fn.jQuery.ready @ jquery.js:242bootstrapApplication @ app.js:56processQueue @ angular.js:15097(anonymous function) @ angular.js:15113Scope.$eval @ angular.js:16359Scope.$digest @ angular.js:16175Scope.$apply @ angular.js:16467done @ angular.js:10852completeRequest @ angular.js:11050requestLoaded @ angular.js:10991
>   noframework.waypoints.min.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: n[t].refresh is not a functione.refreshAll @ noframework.waypoints.min.js:7window.onload @ noframework.waypoints.min.js:7
>   2angular.js:12783 TypeError: handlers.push is not a function
>       at Object.jQuery.event.add (http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js:4426:14)
>       at HTMLDivElement. (http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js:5079:17)
>       at Function.jQuery.extend.each (http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js:590:23)
>       at jQuery.fn.jQuery.each (http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js:237:17)
>       at jQuery.fn.extend.on (http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js:5078:15)
>       at jQuery.fn.extend.bind (http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js:6738:15)
>       at Function. (http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js:741:13)
>       at Function.jQuery.extend.each (http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js:598:23)
>       at $.Widget._on (http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js:715:5)
>       at $.Widget._createWidget (http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js:565:9) (anonymous function) @ angular.js:12783(anonymous function) @ angular.js:9535(anonymous function) @ angular-block-ui.js:22invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:9081nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8566compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7965publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7845boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7983controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:8593ngRepeatAction @ angular.js:28080$watchCollectionAction @ angular.js:16066Scope.$digest @ angular.js:16203Scope.$apply @ angular.js:16467done @ angular.js:10852completeRequest @ angular.js:11050requestLoaded @ angular.js:10991
>   2angular.js:12783 TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>       at Function.jQuery.extend.each (http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js:564:16)
>       at $.widget._setHandleClassName (http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js:13580:5)
>       at ._setHandleClassName (http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js:415:25)
>       at $.widget._setOption (http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js:13574:9)
>       at ._setOption (http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js:415:25)
>       at $.Widget._setOptions (http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js:665:9)
>       at $.Widget.option (http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js:657:8)
>       at HTMLDivElement. (http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js:508:39)
>       at Function.jQuery.extend.each (http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js:590:23)
>       at jQuery.fn.jQuery.each (http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js:237:17) undefined(anonymous function) @ angular.js:12783(anonymous function) @ angular.js:9535(anonymous function) @ angular-block-ui.js:22Scope.$digest @ angular.js:16221Scope.$apply @ angular.js:16467done @ angular.js:10852completeRequest @ angular.js:11050requestLoaded @ angular.js:10991
>   jquery.js:2302 Uncaught TypeError: matchExpr[type].exec is not a functiontokenize @ jquery.js:2302Sizzle @ jquery.js:1120jQuery.fn.extend.find @ jquery.js:5158(anonymous function) @ sidenav.js:21
>   2angular.js:12783 TypeError: matchExpr[type].exec is not a function
>       at tokenize (http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js:2302:36)
>       at Function.Sizzle [as find] (http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js:1120:14)
>       at jQuery.fn.extend.find (http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js:5158:11)
>       at jQuery.fn.jQuery.init (http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js:168:38)
>       at jQuery (http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js:63:10)
>       at $.widget._refreshItems (http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js:14162:129)
>       at ._refreshItems (http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js:415:25)
>       at $.widget.refresh (http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js:14097:8)
>       at .refresh (http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js:415:25)
>       at HTMLDivElement. (http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js:508:39) undefined(anonymous function) @ angular.js:12783(anonymous function) @ angular.js:9535(anonymous function) @ angular-block-ui.js:22(anonymous function) @ angular.js:18246completeOutstandingRequest @ angular.js:5754(anonymous function) @ angular.js:6031
>   angular-animate.js:2347 Uncaught TypeError: list.filter is not a functionfilterFromRegistry @ angular-animate.js:2347$animate.off @ angular-animate.js:2388cleanupEventListeners @ angular-animate.js:2358(anonymous function) @ angular-animate.js:2716(anonymous function) @ angular-animate.js:2263notifyProgress @ angular-animate.js:2702(anonymous function) @ angular-animate.js:2695(anonymous function) @ angular.js:5623forEach @ angular.js:341AnimateRunner._resolve @ angular.js:5622(anonymous function) @ angular.js:5615(anonymous function) @ angular.js:5472AnimateRunner._tick @ angular.js:5539AnimateRunner.complete @ angular.js:5614close @ angular-animate.js:3270(anonymous function) @ angular-animate.js:3076(anonymous function) @ angular.js:5623forEach @ angular.js:341AnimateRunner._resolve @ angular.js:5622(anonymous function) @ angular.js:5615(anonymous function) @ angular.js:5472AnimateRunner._tick @ angular.js:5539AnimateRunner.complete @ angular.js:5614close @ angular-animate.js:1298onAnimationProgress @ angular-animate.js:1354jQuery.event.dispatch @ jquery.js:4676elemData.handle @ jquery.js:4360
>   2app-run.js:78 Uncaught TypeError: f is not a function(anonymous function) @ app-run.js:78Object.fold @ app-run.js:78jQuery.extend.access @ jquery.js:779jQuery.extend.access @ jquery.js:751jQuery.fn.extend.css @ jquery.js:6169applyAnimationToStyles @ angular-animate.js:221triggerAnimationStart @ angular-animate.js:1513start @ angular-animate.js:1396(anonymous function) @ angular-animate.js:959(anonymous function) @ angular-animate.js:411
>   app-run.js:78 Uncaught TypeError: f is not a function(anonymous function) @ app-run.js:78Object.fold @ app-run.js:78jQuery.extend.access @ jquery.js:779jQuery.extend.access @ jquery.js:751jQuery.fn.extend.css @ jquery.js:6169applyAnimationToStyles @ angular-animate.js:221applyAnimationStyles @ angular-animate.js:209close @ angular-animate.js:1266onAnimationProgress @ angular-animate.js:1354jQuery.event.dispatch @ jquery.js:4676elemData.handle @ jquery.js:4360
>   angular.js:12783 TypeError: matchExpr[type].exec is not a function
>       at tokenize (http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js:2302:36)
>       at Function.Sizzle [as find] (http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js:1120:14)
>       at jQuery.fn.extend.find (http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js:5158:11)
>       at setLegend (http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.js:333:32)
>       at createChart (http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.js:202:59)
>       at http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.js:149:13
>       at Scope.$digest (http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/angular/angular.js:16203:23)
>       at Scope.$apply (http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/angular/angular.js:16467:24)
>       at done (http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10852:47)
>       at completeRequest (http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/angular/angular.js:11050:7) undefined(anonymous function) @ angular.js:12783(anonymous function) @ angular.js:9535(anonymous function) @ angular-block-ui.js:22Scope.$digest @ angular.js:16221Scope.$apply @ angular.js:16467done @ angular.js:10852completeRequest @ angular.js:11050requestLoaded @ angular.js:10991
>   app-run.js:78 Uncaught TypeError: f is not a function(anonymous function) @ app-run.js:78Object.fold @ app-run.js:78jQuery.extend.access @ jquery.js:779jQuery.extend.access @ jquery.js:751jQuery.fn.extend.css @ jquery.js:6169applyAnimationToStyles @ angular-animate.js:221triggerAnimationStart @ angular-animate.js:1513start @ angular-animate.js:1396(anonymous function) @ angular-animate.js:959(anonymous function) @ angular-animate.js:411
>   app-run.js:78 Uncaught TypeError: f is not a function(anonymous function) @ app-run.js:78Object.fold @ app-run.js:78jQuery.extend.access @ jquery.js:779jQuery.extend.access @ jquery.js:751jQuery.fn.extend.css @ jquery.js:6169applyAnimationToStyles @ angular-animate.js:221applyAnimationStyles @ angular-animate.js:209close @ angular-animate.js:1266onAnimationProgress @ angular-animate.js:1354jQuery.event.dispatch @ jquery.js:4676elemData.handle @ jquery.js:4360
>   angular.js:12783 TypeError: list.filter is not a function
>       at filterFromRegistry (http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js:2347:19)
>       at Object.$animate.off (http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js:2388:43)
>       at cleanupEventListeners (http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js:2358:18)
>       at http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js:2716:13
>       at http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js:2263:11
>       at notifyProgress (http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js:2702:9)
>       at http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js:2695:11
>       at http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/angular/angular.js:5623:13
>       at forEach (http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/angular/angular.js:341:20)
>       at Object.AnimateRunner._resolve (http://{{development}}.com/bower_components/angular/angular.js:5622:11) undefined

Comment: Is it happening only once or it 's repeating?

Comment: @RomanC the console log `im beign called` happens once per reload. then i get errors such as `TypeError: (tweeners[prop] || []).concat is not a function` or `Uncaught TypeError: n[t].refresh is not a function` or `TypeError: handlers.push is not a function` and so on....
If i comment the reduce inclusion everything works smoothly

Comment: Please, post full error messages with call stack, especially if there may be differences. Also, you can just add a breakpoint there and figure out who's calling it; something that people on SO can't do for you.

Comment: can you provide working sample on [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: @Grundy it works http://jsfiddle.net/Illiax/Lvc0u55v/4974/, not in my world but works in fiddle. It is called with window object by itself though.

Comment: so, posibly problem not in angular, but in around code?

Comment: @Grundy im trying to figure it out, may be deeper... since if I comment the lines inside the if (!object...) it works.